# How to use electron-nightly with typescript properly?

Tags: typescript, electron, nightly-build

I'm novice and can't understand how to use `electron-nightly` package properly. And I can't find **any information** about it. But I need `electron-nightly` due it has support of ESM.

I use **typescript 5.1.3**

**main.ts**:

```
`import { app } from 'electron';`
```

**package.json**:

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@types/node": "^20.5.9",
    "electron-nightly": "^28.0.0-nightly.20230908",
    "typescript": "~5.1.3"
}
```

**tsconfig.json**:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "types": [
      "node",
      "electron-nightly"
    ],
  ...
}
```

Compile from ts to js done without any errors, but if I try to run compiled app by `electron .` I get error

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\electron\cli.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:933:15)
    at Function.Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:778:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:77:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:17:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
```

I tried:

1. `import { app } from 'electron-nightly'` but got error:

```
`File 'c:/WORKSPACE/MyProject/node_modules/electron-nightly/electron.d.ts' is not a module.ts(2306)`
```

2. `npm i electron` and `import { app } from 'electron'` but got error of definitions duplicate in `electron` and `electron-nightly`:

```
Definitions of the following identifiers conflict with those in another file...
```

3. rename package `electron-nightly` into `electron` in my node_modules folder (please don't laugh so loud I was so desperate :))) but got error:

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\electron\cli.js'
```

So my questions:

- Should I install `electron` package with `npm i electron` in addition? And how should I bind my code with `electron-nightly` in this case?
- Which package should be imported in main.ts? And If it's `electron-nightly` so how to resolve `...is not a module.ts`?
- Further I would package my app with `electron-forge`, so  would any problems with it?

Thanks!

Comment: Hello. I am experiencing similar problems. I have found that the `electron-forge start` command works OK with ESM. Therefore for the time being during development I am copying the contents of node_modules/electron/dist and my web-deployed app into a folder with a batch file to run it in 'debug' mode. When electron 28 arrives in november I can then see whether I can deploy from that.

Answer (score 0):

You probably didn't define in the environment variables the path of the node in your windows.

That's why the nodejs module is not found as the initial error says

```
Error: Cannot find module 'C:\Program Files\nodejs\node_modules\electron\cli.js'
```

Try setting it like this on your windows, run this in the command line.

```
 SET PATH=C:\Program Files\Nodejs;%PATH%
```

1 - You don't need to install the electron package separately if you're using electron-nightly.

2 - The "duplicate definitions" error you are experiencing occurs because you are trying to import Electron modules from two different sources: 'electron' and 'electron-nightly'. Only use Electron Nightly

3 -  Electron Forge should work fine with Electron Nightly if you have it set up correctly.

Comment: Ramon, thanks for your answer! I use NVM and I found there was globally installed 'electron' package, probably it was the problem. After I uninstalled it and reinstalled 'electron-nightly' everything works fine!

Answer (score 0):

Had the same problem. E.g. I am using webpack-electron, which directly references `electron`, so no easy way to change that. Solved it using the alias functionality of npm and yarn:

npm:

`npm install electron@npm:electron-nightly --save`

yarn:

`yarn add electron@npm:electron-nightly`

Has the extra benefit you can just change to nightly versions without updating your code...